# how to prove this property of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

> $$\left(m+n\right) \cdot \vec a= m \cdot \vec a + n \cdot \vec a$$

I have tried to prove that both sides have the same magnitude and direction, but got nothing.

Comment: this is one of the axioms for a vector space, maybe you need to prove it for a specific "vector space"

Comment: what rules can you use?

Comment: Clearly the direction will not change since we only manipulate $\vec{a}$. Now the size : On the RHS you will have $m$ times the size of $\vec{a}$ + $n$ times the size of $\vec{a}$ over all this gives $m+n$ times the size of $\vec{a}$.

Comment: [Duplicate question?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109142/proving-that-the-dot-product-is-distributive)

Comment: I think what they want you to do is take $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, i.e.  $a=<a_1,a_2,...a_n>$ and compute $(m+n) a$ Then using the definition of scalar multiplication and vector addition show that this is equal to $ma+na$. Also why do you have a dot product there? Aren't $m$ and $n$ scalers?